# How to check the latest Solidity version supported by Truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I ve been reading truffle docs but didnt find anything related to this. My question arises since i would like to start writing in 0.8 version which solves the underflow/overflow issue, but i couldnt find whether its supported by truffle, which is the framework i am most familiar with. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction here ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Once you install truffle, you can run following command which gives you list of all supported solidity versions:

```sh
truffle compile --list
```

Then you can specify the compile version inside `truffle-config.js`. For example:

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ... etc ...
  },
  compilers: {
     solc: {
       version: "0.8.4" 
     }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's currently 0.6.12.

`@truffle/compile-solidity`'s latest version 5.2.1 has a dependency on `solc` in the version `^0.6.0`. Which means any version with backwards compatibility to 0.6.0, and the latest compatible is 0.6.12.

Sources:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/compile-solidity - Latest version 5.2.1
- https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/master/packages/compile-solidity/package.json - package.json for version 5.2.1 showing dependency on `solc` ^0.6.0
- https://etherscan.io/solcversions - List of `solc` versions

Comment: Actually i found this doc : https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0#bring-your-own-compiler ; and i managed to work with solidity 0.8.1 now successfully so far.